# Why does AWS/KMS restrict ListAliases to the current account?

Tags: amazon-kms

KMS allows you to grant access to keys in other accounts in order to perform operations like Encrypt, Decrypt, and GenerateDataKey. Meanwhile, the kms:ListAliases docs state: "You cannot list aliases in other accounts." Would be nice if I could grant the root of another account ability to grant ListAliases using the same mechanism we have for other operations. (Obviously this would require a new field in ListAliases, something like "AccountArn" that would default to the current account.) Anyone here working on KMS know what the thinking behind the restriction is?

Comment: From the docs, it seems like you can create an alias which points to another account.

Comment: That's correct. I use that for known aliases. But if you want to look for alias's named given a particular pattern, you can't do that right now. E.g.: When manually rotating keys, you might want to keep track of old keys under a renamed alias to decrypt files still in transit. The particular use case I'm thinking of is a new instance spun up after a rotation, but before messages encrypted with the rotated key have been received.